# Convert Hexadecimal Floating-Point Constant

Tags: floating-point

I have some constants to convert, they are defined as follow :

0x1.0p-126f

0x1.fffffep127f

0x1.0p-23f

How can I convert them accurately ?

BTW, it is because Visual Studio does not support this notation !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a non-C99 compliant compiler, you can write:

```
0x1.0p-126f -> ldexp (1.0, -126) 

0x1.fffffep127f -> ldexp(0x1fffffe,  127 - 4 * 6)

0x1.0p-23f -> ldexp(1.0, -23)
```

In the second example, the `6` is the number of hexadecimal digits that were after the dot. The original had `0x1.fffffe` so when I wrote the integer `0x1fffffe`, I wrote a quantity 2<sup>4</sup> times larger for each digit I shifted from after the point to before the point, which should be compensated for with the second argument.

Function `ldexp()` is standard:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>  #include <math.h>
>
>  double
>  ldexp(double x, int n);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>  The ldexp() functions multiply x by 2 to the power n.
> ```

If these expressions appear in a place where constant expressions are expected, then function calls are not an acceptable substitute.
In this case, simply print the result of the `ldexp()` calls with a C program and the format `%.16e`, and use the printed value in substitution for the original.