# C# hexadecimal floating-point constants

Tags: c#, floating-point, hex

I'd like to use some hexa floating point constants with exponents in C# as it is allowed in c++
For example :
0x1p+53 or
0x1.dcd651ep+29

Can't find a way how to translate this to C#.  I'm using VS2019

BTW i'm aware of the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826876/convert-hexadecimal-floating-point-constant) with a workaround with C.Math lib (ldexp) but I'm using .net 5 and I can't rely on a .net 4.x lib.

Comment: Convert the hex to decimal first? What do these values actually mean?

Comment: it is acually a convienence for unit testing function that handle floating-point values

Comment: But how are they interpreted? I'm not a C++ expert, I'd love an explanation of what the values represent in decimal notation

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal

Comment: C# does not support this. Any reason you don't just convert the hex to decimal by hand? If you have a lot you could write a little script to parse them

Comment: that's exactly what I did!  I was only looking for a more integrated solution if I may.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like there's no other way than convert and use decimal values instead.